# How do run Mongo on Ubuntu Server, getting error

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have been trying to install MongoDB and have been following instructions on the Mongo docs, I am trying to start Mongo and I get this error

[image]

It appears as if it says that the "addr already in use"? I restarted my server and this still comes up I am unsure what to do next.

Comment: It looks like it is already running... try typing "mongo" and see if a mongo shell starts.

Comment: LOL it IS running! Why the hell does it show an error? Thats so weird.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the active mongod server and try it again:

> sudo service mongod stop 
>   sudo mongod